# Does Room allow a non-primitive data type as the primary key?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Using Room, I want to write a Kotlin `@Entity` with a non-primitive data type as its `@PrimaryKey`. For example:

```
@Entity
data class MyEntity(
    @PrimaryKey val myType: MyType,
    val text: String
)
```

I am providing a TypeConverter between my non-primitive type to/from a String.

```
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter fun fromString(value: String): MyType = MyTypeUtil.parse(value)
    @TypeConverter fun toString(myType: MyType) = myType.toString()
}
```

I'm also properly registering my `TypeConverter`s on my database:

```
@Database(
    entities = [
        MyEntity::class
    ],
    version = 1
)
@TypeConverters(
    Converters::class
)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun myDao(): MyDao
}
```

Compilation is failing with:

`...MyDao_Impl.java: uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.`

Can you help me find the problem? Does Room allow what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - Room allow non-primitive data types as the primary key.

You have bug in your `TypeConverters` - you must provide conversions from `String` to `MyType` and from `MyType` to `String`, so method `fromString` must return `MyType` (right now it is returning `String`). Change that and it should work :)
If you would still be having weird compile errors, try to Clean Project after making the changes.

Comment: I apologize - I typed my sample code incorrectly. I edited the signature bug you mentioned. I will try your suggestion in a minimal sample project to verify the fix.

Comment: I got things working in a sample project with `MyType` as the `PrimaryKey`. I'll report back after trying to fix my original project. Thank you!

Comment: I got things working in my original project as well. Thanks for your help!